# Inline css in the react not working dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to show my image in background by using inline `CSS` in `<div>` tag

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(${imageUrl})'}}></div>
```

but its not working its showing unexpected template string expression.

[image is about sc of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWrgN.png)

Comment: this is the code i have written but not getting the image <div style={{
        backgroundImage: 'url(${imageUrl})'
    }}

Comment: Use back tick `\`` (should be on the top left part of your keyboard left to the `1` key) instead of quote. Like this: `<div style={{ backgroundImage: \`url(${imageUrl})\`}} `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), when you want to print dynamic value in string like,

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}
```

**Notice the back tick (`)**